# How to use Row and Column in same time or any other options about my layout Challange

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm watching Angela Yu's Complete Flutter Development Series and in Section 6 in 43. episode there is a layout challenge

[image]

And i solved that like this.

```
home: Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
    body: SafeArea(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 100,
            height: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 200,
            color: Colors.yellow,
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: 100,
            height: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

i dont sure its a correct solution is there any other way to solve this challange ? Or is my way correct.
I am talking about this part of code

```
          Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 200,
            color: Colors.yellow,
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Using margin is optimal when we have custom space requirements. To achieve this UI, place your containers in inside a column which is wrapped with Expanded Widget. And set mainAxisAlignment to Center

Code:

```
body: SafeArea(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 100,
              height: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            Expanded(
                child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.lightGreen,
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                )
              ],
            )),
            Container(
              width: 100,
              height: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.blue,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

OUTPUT:

[image: OUTPUT]

Answer (score 0):

It should be using `Column` instead margin, I think.

```dart
        Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              color: Colors.yellow,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
          ],
        ),
```